Getting empty set of result while using and operator in mysql
While using and operator getting empty result set even the condition of and is true, then what to do to fix this?
I tried to find the result where salary is lees than 30000 and salary is greater than equal to 40000 with the the help of and operator, even if the and condition is True but MYSQL returns an empty result set i.e zero rows.
